# "e.target" calling wrong target?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The component that I'm working on relies on `<img>` elements inside of `<span>` elements, and when the `<span>` detects a "click" event through JQuery, that span's ID should be logged to the console. But for some reason, the `<img>`'s ID is being logged instead.

```js
$(() => {
   $('.star-span').click(e => {
      console.log(e.target);
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span class="star-span" id="1">
   <img class="star-img" width="15%" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/18/Five-pointed_star.svg/2000px-Five-pointed_star.svg.png" />
</span>
```

Anyone see any obvious mistakes in my code?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Behavior is as expected. Per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target), `event.target` is

> A reference to the object that dispatched the event. It is different from `event.currentTarget` when the event handler is called during the bubbling or capturing phase of the event.

The innermost element that was clicked on was the `img`, so the `img` is the `target` of the event.

If you wanted a reference to the element the handler is on, use `e.currentTarget` instead:

```js
$('.star-span').click(e => {
  console.log(e.currentTarget);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span class="star-span" id="1">
   <img class="star-img" width="15%" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/18/Five-pointed_star.svg/2000px-Five-pointed_star.svg.png" />
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is the `e.currentTarget` and not `e.target`. Check the snippet. `e.currentTarget` is what you assigned the listener to. `e.target` is what actually dispatches the event (whatever is under the mouse)

```js
$(() => {
   $('.star-span').click(e => {
      console.log(e.currentTarget);
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span class="star-span" id="1">
   <img class="star-img" width="15%" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/18/Five-pointed_star.svg/2000px-Five-pointed_star.svg.png" />
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have answered using `e.currentTarget` can work. There is also one more way using `function` instead of `arrow` and you will have benefit of having `this` object also. You can also use `e.currentTarget` here.

```js
$(() => {
    $('.star-span').click(function(e){
        console.log(this);
        console.log(e.currentTarget);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span class="star-span" id="1">
   <img class="star-img" width="15%" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/18/Five-pointed_star.svg/2000px-Five-pointed_star.svg.png" />
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
   $('.star-span').click(e => {
 console.log(e.currentTarget.id);
   })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<span class="star-span" id="1">
   <img class="star-img" width="5%" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/18/Five-pointed_star.svg/2000px-Five-pointed_star.svg.png" />
</span>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would delegate and use closest

```js
$(() => {
  $('#container').on('click','.star-span',e => {
    const tgt = e.target.closest('.star-span');
    if (tgt) console.log(tgt.id)
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <span class="star-span" id="star1"><img class="star-img" width="15%" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/18/Five-pointed_star.svg/2000px-Five-pointed_star.svg.png" /></span>
  <span class="star-span" id="star2"><img class="star-img" width="15%" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/18/Five-pointed_star.svg/2000px-Five-pointed_star.svg.png" /></span>
  <span class="star-span" id="star3"><img class="star-img" width="15%" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/18/Five-pointed_star.svg/2000px-Five-pointed_star.svg.png" /></span>
</div>
```